# Resetting a user's password

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to find a solution for resetting user's passwords (all users, not just the authenticated user) in Azure Active directory via a non-interactive login.

Right now it seems this is only available via powershell's MSOnline [`Set-AzureADUserPassword` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Azuread/Set-AzureADUserPassword?view=azureadps-2.0) using a Service Principal login.

I'd like to find a solution using an API Endpoint so I can use C#. The closest solutions I've found was [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/) but after setting it up, I realized I can only reset the passwords via an interactive login and consent flow. It's not allowed via non-interactive.

My next attempt is to use [Azure AD endpoint](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console/) but my concern is I am seeing the same message that recommends that we use the Microsoft graph API. Does this means azure ad endpoint will be going away?

Is there a recommended approach without using PowerShell?

Answer (score 7):

You could update user's `passwordProfile` property to reset user's password :

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}
Content-type: application/json
Authorization: bearer TOKEN

{
     "passwordProfile":
    {
      "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn":false,
      "password": "XXXXXXXXX"
    }

}
```

As explanation in [document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_update) :

> > When updating the passwordProfile property, the following permission is required: Directory.AccessAsUser.All.

Then you could use [Resource Owner Flow](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2016/09/25/resource-owner-password-credentials-grant-in-azure-ad-oauth/) as the requirement needs non-interactive login . To enable `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` delegate permission, you should :

1. Add Microsoft Graph's `Access directory as the signed in user` permission in `Required permissions` blade of your Azure AD app :
   [image]
2. That permission needs admin consent , please click `Grant Permissions` button with your admin account .

Then you could use Resource Owner Flow to acquire access token for Microsoft Graph , `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` permission allows an Admin to change another user's password in your tenant .

> > Does this means azure ad endpoint will be going away?

Currently , Microsoft Graph supports most of the directory features that Azure AD Graph supports, but not all.  Please refer to [Gaps between Microsoft Graph and Azure AD Graph](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2016/07/08/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/)

Comment: Does this approach work with Azure AD "Free" license?

Comment: @ashin Yes , it supports

Comment: Just wanted to add that this will work with the Graph Module "Update-MgUser" function. Thanks.