# Can’t able to change/reset Azure AD user password by Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I use Microsoft Graph (GraphServiceClient) to create/update user data to Azure AD in ASP .NET Core 2.0. There is no problem in creating user, update user details. But not able to change/reset user password through this.

In Azure:
I have Azure free subscription and created an APP to get/update user **(using clientid and secret)**. I also provide below permission to Microsoft Graph in Azure portal.

[Microsoft Graph permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZC0S.png)

Still not able to update password by using below code returns error “Code: Authorization_RequestDenied  Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.”

[Graph C# client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlQqN.png)

Is there any way to update password using Microsoft Graph using c# ?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow :)

It looks like your permissions are not enough. Check out this question:
[Resetting a user's password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46077799/resetting-a-users-password)

The minimum required permission to change the passwordProfile is the `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` which will require an **admin consent**.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

But I use Microsoft Graph App to update user (using client id and secret). We only need Application permission to process. Directory.AccessAsUser.All is a Delegate permission. We also checked Directory.AccessAsUser.All but it'is not working.